# Edge-disjoint paths in trees

Tags: binary-trees

How do I prove the following proposition?

> Let $T$ be a tree, and let $S$ be a subset of the vertices. If $|S|$ is even then we can partition $S$ into pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ such that the paths $x_i-y_i$ are edge-disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Suppose that $\ell$ is a leaf of $T$ which doesn't belong to $S$. Then we can safely remove $\ell$.
- Suppose that $\ell$ is a leaf of $T$ which does belong to $S$. If its unique neighbor is also in $S$, then we can safely pair them up.
- Suppose that $\ell$ is a leaf of $T$ which belongs to $S$, but its unique neighbor $r$ doesn't belong to $S$. We can safely remove $\ell$ and replace it in $S$ by $r$.

(How to implement these ideas efficiently is a different matter, but for an existence proof these ideas suffice.)

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it separately.